# How can I implement "stripslashes"?

Tags: c++, string

I want to know how I can implement a function in C++ which takes a string which contains escaped control characters, and unescape them(eg `Hello\\nWorld\\n` to `Hello\nWorld\n`).

Is there a way to implement such a function without resorting to case by case mapping from each two-character escape sequence that starts with a slash to the corresponding single character control char?

Here's a test case I want to pass:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using std::string;

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    // before transformation.
    string given("Hello\\nWorld\\n");

    // after transformation.
    string expected("Hello\nWorld\n");

    // transformation :: string -> string
    auto transformation = [](const string &given) -> string {
        // do something to strip slashes from given, and return it.
        string result = given;
        return result;
    };

    string result(transformation(given));

    // test :: (string, string) -> bool
    auto test = [](const string &result, const string &expected) -> bool {
        // returns true if the two given strings are equal, false otherwise.
        return (result.compare(expected) == 0);
    };

    puts(given.c_str());
    puts(result.c_str());
    std::cout << "test result: " << test(result, expected) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking for.  Escape sequences only arise within C++ source code string / character literals.

Comment: I am asking if I have a string with added slashes, how can I "eval" them to turn escaped control literals, such as "\\n" into "\n".

Comment: You are confusing what you see in your source code string literals to something you may get as input at runtime.  Look at your description ("Hello\nWorld\n" to "Hello\nWorld\n") -- See the confusion?  They are both the same.  As to "\\n", if you get that as input, that means the user typed in a single slash followed by the 'n', and your debugger (or whatever you're viewing the string) possibly shows "\\n".

Comment: My bad, typing "Hello\n\nWorld\n\n" escapes to "Hello\nWorld\n" in my post; I put it in backticks. Oddly it doesn't happen in comments section.

Comment: LOL.  Now you see?  Even the posting window is confused.  So basically you want to transform a run of duplicate escape sequences to a single escape sequence?

Comment: yeah; in JavaScript: `var f = "Hello\\nWorld\\n"; var res = eval('"' + f + '"');`. I'm curious if there is a way to do something like this in C++ without resorting to constructing a lookup dictionary for all possible escape sequences, or regex extensions, or loading a scripting runtime to delegate the task to(or resorting to delegating to piping the request to perl).

Comment: `stdio.h` is a C header and AFAIK in modern C++ you should be using `cstdio` instead (things will be in the `std` namespace though).

Comment: @tambre there will never be a namespace clash in this test program, and if it was production code, it would not use stdout for logging; I trust stdio.h more than cstdio not to act in unexpected ways, even though as far as I know both are essentially the same except cstdio mangles the functions in stdio.h making it harder to use gdb for; the net cost/benefit of using stdio.h and cstdio  is zero as far as i know. Considering how important backward compatibility is; even if they're not in global namespace, you're safer to assume they are anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard to write an escaper

```
  std::string stripslashes(std:string const &str)
  {
     std::string answer;
     int i = 0;

    while(i < str.size())
    {
         if(i != '\\')
           answer.pushback(str[i++]);
         else 
         {
             switch(str[i+1])
             {
                case 'n': answer.push_back('\n'); break;
                case 't': answer.push_back('\t'); break;
                ... etc
             }
             i += 2;
         }
     }
   return answer
   }
```

If you want to optimise the switch you ca use a look-up table, but it's hardly worth it.

Comment: i was considering that(except with unordered map for O(1) mapping of 2 character std::strings to the control characters), but while your solution makes the program do an O(N) loop for every single character(which is amazingly fast, but ugly),and my solution requires expensive installation cost of adding all the pairs to the dictionary. I was hoping there was a C++ runtime utility that already has the tables set up to take advantage of; but otherwise it might indeed be impossible to do this without your own runtime(unless you statically construct unordered map from std array, but im not sure)-

Comment: -- i'm not sure if std::unordered_map constructed with std::array constructed at compile-time is indeed created at compile time, or if it still has an installation cost of setting up the table. Even then, both solutions require ugly setup code or boilerplate code.

Comment: actually im sure that a single 256 byte array is enough, since each possible backslashed character is unique. simple look up by the byte of distinct part of escaped sequence, eg 'n' for `\\n`

Comment: Yes. The snag is you can't check that the 256-byte table is correct by inspection. But that gains a bit of speed. So too does using a char * instead of an std::string and doing it in-place.

Comment: std::string from literal is constructed at compile time as far as i know, there's a slight size overhead for std::string, but speedwise it should be the same if not faster in more demanding cases(when allocations are needed, string is pretty clever); such a table can be hardcoded but that's indeed hard to test, it's better to have a scripting language generate the table for you and run tests on it's internal representation before dumping the 256 byte table.